# How to get a list of concrete Exceptions thrown by a method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

Is is possible to get a list (and catch) of the concrete exceptions that can be thrown by a method?

I am calling an API that uses a hierarchy of exceptions, but only declares the top level exception to a method.  I want to be able to provide specific behaviour based on the exception, but I don't want to have to trace through the code to find the concrete exceptions that can be thrown.

There may be added complications that the API contains a number of layers separated by interfaces.

Simple example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void doShakyStuff() throws Exception;
}

public class MyImpl implements MyInterface {
  public void doShakyStuff() throws Exception{
    double rand = Math.random();
    if( rand > 0.1 ){
      throw new IOException();
    }
    if( rand > 0.5 ){
      throw new IllegalAccessException();
    }
    else{
      throw new InterruptedException();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to create the following try/catch as completely as possible and then tweak afterwards:

```
public class MyClass{
  private MyInterface interface;

  public void doStuff(){
    try{
      interface.doShakyStuff();
    }catch(IOException e){
      // ...
    } catch( IllegalAccessException e){
      // ...
    } catch( InterruptedException e){
      // ...
    } catch(Exception e){
      // something else
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For checked exceptions, just invoke the method, Eclipse will give you errors if you haven't caught all of them. For unchecked exceptions, no, there is no such utility as they can come from anywhere.

Comment: How should Eclipse do that? By reading all sources? What if you've got some compiled classes in a jar file?

Comment: And what if you have some classes that are not even available to eclipse?  For instance, in JARs that are downloaded at runtime?

Comment: Eclipse, specifically JDT plugins, builds a model of your code.  This is how it can provide things like call hierarchy, auto complete, etc.  I was wondering whether this extended to the Exception hierarchies.  Anything would be half measures and potentially incomplete, but would be useful nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: no.

The method declares what it throws. If it's only declaring a top-level exception (i.e. `Exception` in your example) ... then that's all your IDE is going to know about / tell you to catch.

To find every subclass it could throw you'd have to look at the javadocs and/or code to find the subclasses or specific subclass being thrown that you're interested in.

Ultimately if you're using an API that's throwing a superclass of an exception, and there's some reason you need to know the concrete subclass ... it's a badly designed API. The point of throwing the superclass when writing an API is that there's only a single line of logic to deal with it regardless of which subclass is really being thrown.

Comment: I thought that this was probably the case, but since Eclipse has an AST of the compiled code, I thought that it might be able to track down references that it knows about.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too.

```
try{
  interface.doShakyStuff();
}catch(Exception e){
     if(e instanceof IOException){
     }
     if( e instanceof IllegalAccessException ){
     }
     if( e instanceof InterruptedException ){
     } 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than just 3 or 4 (if you want to put Exception at the bottom similar to an else) `IOException`, `IllegalAccessException`, and `InterruptedException`catch blocks?

Comment: No this does not answer my question.  I understand the different options for Exception handling.  My question was specifically whether Eclipse could provide the list of exceptions.